# Xamarin - GCM OnMessageReceived method not called

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I'm able to get the registration token id from gcm but my problem is that when i send the message to the client app i don't receive it on Xamarin Android Player. I followed the example on this site : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/

Here is my code :

**MainActivity.cs**

```
 [Activity(Label = "ResApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        TextView msgText;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            msgText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.msgText);

            if (IsPlayServicesAvailable()) //this check if google play is installed
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
                StartService(intent);
            }
        }

        public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
            {
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                    msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
                else
                {
                    msgText.Text = "Sorry, this device is not supported";
                    Finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**RegistrationIntentService.cs**

```
  [Service(Exported = false)]
    class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
                lock (locker)
                {
                    var SenderID = "xxxxx";
                    var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
                    var token = instanceID.GetToken(SenderID, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                    Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                    SendRegistrationToAppServer(token);
                    Subscribe(token);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
                return;
            }
        }

        void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation here as needed.
        }

        void Subscribe(string token)
        {
            var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
            pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
        }
    }
```

**InstanceIdListenerService.cs**

```
 [Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
    class MyInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
    {
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
            StartService(intent);
        }
    }
```

**GcmListenerService.cs**

```
 [Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
    public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
        {
            var message = data.GetString("message");
            Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "From:    " + from);
            Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: " + message);
            SendNotification(message);
        }

        void SendNotification(string message)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .SetContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="co.za.resapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="ResApp"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="co.za.resapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED" />
    <permission android:name="co.za.resapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="CodeLog">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="co.za.resapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Send Message from Server**

```
 var jGcmData = new JObject();
            var jData = new JObject();

            jData.Add("message", MESSAGE);
            jGcmData.Add("to", "/topics/global");
            jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

            var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

                    Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                        new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                            .ContinueWith(response =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(response);
                                Console.WriteLine("Message sent: check the client device notification tray.");
                            }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to send GCM message:");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

Comment: Show your MainActivity code

Comment: I have added the MainActivity code

Comment: Still not working? Sometimes when creating a new GCM key it can take a few minutes before it's working.

Comment: Yes still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there was a problem in the manifest file. I pasted this new code in the manifest code and the program worked :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="co.za.resapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
  <application android:label="GCM_ANDROID">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="co.za.resapp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="co.za.resapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```